# Animating a container as soon as it is added to a widget list (as it appears )

Tags: android, dart, flutter

how to animate the added containers as soon as they appear ? ( animation of height going from 0 to containerHeight)

here is a code to illustrate my question:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

List<Widget> widgetList = [Container()];

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Animated container'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        //shift to left
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 55.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: widgetList.toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    add(controller.text);
                  });
                },
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Clear',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widgetList.clear();
                  });
                },
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              TextField(
                onChanged: (text) {},
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                controller: controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                  fillColor: Colors.blue,
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void add(String containerHeight) {
  widgetList.add(Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
        ),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 165),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        //color: Colors.red,
        height: double.parse(containerHeight),
        width: 29.0,
        child: Text(
          containerHeight,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: containerHeight.length == 1
                  ? 19.0
                  : containerHeight.length == 2
                      ? 19.0
                      : containerHeight.length == 3
                          ? 16.0
                          : containerHeight.length == 4 ? 14.0 : 10.0),
        ),
      )));
}
```

[Screenshot of the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unNqU.png)

You just have to put the height of the container in the text field and press 'add', then the containers will appear directly without animation,
so my question is how to animate so that the height goes from 0 to containerHeight ?

i know it works when the widget is already there and we modify it's height, but i couldn't figure out how to do in that scenario ( adding to a list and displaying it directly ).

thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `AnimatedList` ?

Comment: looks like it can do the trick, but seems ahead of my skills, is it possible to have some direction of how to use it in this case please ?

Comment: update : a workaround by making two list, one widget list and another containing height of the said widgets in order (initially 0),  then updating the height values makes the container seem to just being added with an animation.
any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It is working.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'dart:async';

  void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));
  }

  class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
  }

  List<Widget> widgetList = [Container()];
  StreamController<String> animationStream = StreamController();


  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Animated container'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          //shift to left
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 55.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: widgetList.toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Add',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    animationStream = StreamController();
                    setState(() {
                      add("0");

                      animationStream.sink.add(controller.text);
                    });
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Clear',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widgetList.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (text) {},
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  controller: controller,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    fillColor: Colors.blue,
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void add(String containerHeight) {
    widgetList.add(new MyWidget());
  }

  class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyWidget({
      Key key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: animationStream.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          String _hight = "0";
          if (snapshot.hasData ) {

            _hight = snapshot.data;
            try { double.parse(_hight);} catch (e) { print('please enter a valid hight');_hight="0"; }
          }

            return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2165),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  //color: Colors.red,
                  height: double.parse(_hight),
                  width: 29.0,
                  child: Text(
                    _hight,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: _hight.length == 1
                            ? 19.0
                            : _hight.length == 2
                                ? 19.0
                                : _hight.length == 3
                                    ? 16.0
                                    : _hight.length == 4 ? 14.0 : 10.0),
                  ),
                ));

        },
      );
    }
  }
```